# Windows 11 taskbar icons invisible

Tags: windows-11

I don't know how to reproduce the issue. So don't ask.
See that image of my current task bar:

[image]

The spaces between the icons you see are "occupied" by pinned programs.
The links are working. I simply do not see the icons.

If I hover them, I can see the tooltip telling me what this icon is.
When I click one, the program opens and the icon suddenly reveals. Just that one.

It happends randomly... Once or two over a month or so.
When I notice it happened again, I don't realy know how much time it's like that.
The only solution I actually have is to reboot.

This is just annoying.

I suspect the recover from sleep mode a lot.

**So the question is**: what should I look for to fix that weird issue?
Give me a hint. A keyword to search on...

**Edit**
I also need to mention that I simply **refused** the configuration step where the user should create a MS account... Since 2019 (I had windows 10 at the time... Upgraded I don't know when and up to date as of now)
They keep on asking me at almost every reboot.
I do NOT want their cloud storage mouth-forced solution.

Would this be possible a reason?

Comment: Not much to go on. Try DISM / SFC ....   dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  followed by SFC /scannow  ...   Allow all to complete, restart  and test.

Comment: Now sure how to correctly type in those CLI commands... Can you develop in an answer?

Comment: I provided a full answer for you and trust  you will acknowledge it

Answer (score 0):

There is not much here to go on. Since the problem is intermittent, it may be possible to fix with the initial Windows repair steps:  DISM  followed by SFC.

1. open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator .
2. dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image /startcomponentclenanup  /resetbase  .
3. dism.exe  /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth .
4. SFC /SCANNOW  .

When the above is complete, restart.

With respect to Microsoft Accounts, I use them and they work very well. You do not have to, but I recommend that you do.

However, I am quite certain that not having a Microsoft account is a cause of the task bar issue.  I have a Windows 10 VM with a local account and  no task bar issue.

If the above fails to resolve the issue, you would then need to do a Windows 11 Repair Install

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows is running, so click on download (not upgrade), you may need a USB for download. Run Setup on the USB Key and select Keep Everything

Comment: Nice! thanks a ton John. I will try that. But not RFN because, I did not expect an answer that quick in fact (my best bet was to get downvoted until I delete). I actually have things running on my pc and it's not the right time for a reboot. But I will get back to this very soon. -- I upvote you anyway.

Comment: I also added a Repair Install step as you may need this also.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with the icon for OneNote (invisible) and tried all the recommendations about clearing icon cache, SFC, DISM and everything else. What fixed it for me was to restore the icon association for PNG.
Download **png.reg** from here
**https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8703-restore-default-file-type-associations-windows-10-a.html#option2**
and run it.
Magic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).